# Data transpose using Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, string-concatenation

I'm having table and data like below,

```
Create table transpose (a number, b number, c number); 

insert into transpose values (1,4,7);
insert into transpose values (2,5,8); 
insert into transpose values (3,6,9); 
commit; 
select * from transpose; 

A B C 
1 4 7 
2 5 8 
3 6 9
```

Question: I need below output using sql query, Is this possbile to
    retrive data (Transpose data)?

```
   A B C 
   1 2 3 
   4 5 6 
   7 8 9
```

Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Your table *transpose* has no order. Does a transpose operation make sense without order?

Comment: Lookup 'pivot' in the Oracle docs

Comment: @WW. good point; I updated the solution. I assume that before pivoting, the table must be transformed in the key - value format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two important things to consider.

1) a SQL table has no implicite order, so you must add the *order by* information to uniquely define the columns of the transposed table. (I added a column ID in the table to simulate it).

2) If you are looking for a solution for fixed number of columns and rows, you may code the result in the SQL query see below (For a dynamic solution I'd not recommend to use SQL)

```
 select 
   (select a from transpose where id = 1) a,
   (select a from transpose where id = 2) b,
   (select a from transpose where id = 3) c
 from dual
 union all
 select 
   (select b from transpose where id = 1) a,
   (select b from transpose where id = 2) b,
   (select b from transpose where id = 3) c
 from dual
 union all
 select 
   (select c from transpose where id = 1) a,
   (select c from transpose where id = 2) b,
   (select c from transpose where id = 3) c
 from dual;
```

.

```
     A          B          C
 ---------- ---------- ----------
     1          2          3 
     4          5          6 
     7          8          9
```

**UPDATE - solution with PIVOT**

As proposed by @WW here solution with pivot

```
 with trans as (
 /* add one select for each column */
 select id, 'A' col_name, a col_value from transpose union all
 select id, 'B' col, b col_value from transpose union all
 select id, 'C' col, b col_value from transpose)
 select * from trans
 PIVOT (sum(col_value) col_value 
 for (id) in 
 (1 as "C1", /* add one entry for each row (ID) */
 2 as "C2",
 3 as "C3" )
 )
```